# iOS Bluetooth Connect Callback No Longer Works

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, callback, bluetooth-lowenergy

I had a working BLE app, even archived multiple working versions of it.  All of a sudden I am not receiving the callback when a device is connected. I connect to the periperal when the user taps an entry in a ListView of scanned for devices. Another strange thing is that while analyzing the problem I started with a situation where the connect call is issued, the call back received and then an immediate disconnect call back happens.  So I did a project clean and rebuild.  Then the connect call back stopped being invoked entirely.  I went back to known working versions of the app and they do the same thing (connect call back not happening). Today I was pushed updates to the OS and Xcode on both the iPad and Mac but the same thing happens.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate
{

var btManager:    CBCentralManager!
var btDeviceList: [CBPeripheral] = []
var btDevice:     CBPeripheral!


func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)
{
    print("Found BLE device: " + peripheral.name!);

    // Add the scanner only if its not there already
    var i = 0
    var foundIt = false

    for tempDevice in btDeviceList
    {
        if tempDevice.identifier == peripheral.identifier
        {
            foundIt = true
            break
        }

        i = i + 1
    }

    if (!foundIt)
    {
        btDeviceList.append(peripheral)

        btListView.reloadData()
    }
}

// Called when connected to a BLE device
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral)
{
    print("Connected to: " + peripheral.name!)

    // Discover the services for the device
    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
}

// Called when a row in the table list view is tapped
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    btManager.stopScan()

    btDevice = btDeviceList[indexPath.row]

    btDevice.delegate = self

    print("Connecting to: " + btDevice.name!)
    btManager.connect(btDevice, options: nil)
}

} // View Controller
```

Comment: have you set the "duplicates"scanning key?  You `didDiscover` code doesn't look good.  It removes a potentially connected device from your array, which will cause it to disconnect since you need to hold a strong reference. It would be better to not add the new device if it is already present in the array. Also, just insert a single row into the table, don't reload the whole thing. Finally, compare the `identifier` to determine if the peripheral is the same, not the peripheral name.

Comment: I don't set the duplicates scanning key and it makes sense now because I see duplicates which is why I added the removal code.  So if I make btDevice a strong reference and add the duplicates key I won't need to check if it exists before adding it to the list although it would be good practice.  I'll give it a go.  I'm not sure why it worked before and worked well.

Comment: No, adding the duplicates key would cause a problem,  to resolve it.  Still, there is no reason to remove something from the array if it already there only to add it later; just don't add it again. The common cause of the behaviour you are describing is the peripheral being released, so look at that

Comment: That's exactly what I originally changed, not add it if its there, and the connect problem got in the way before I could test it.  I'm working on maintaining a strong reference to the device.  I'm not too swift with Swift yet (pun intended).

Comment: I updated the discovery code to only add the device if its not there and compare by identifier.  Doesn't appending the peripheral to the btDeviceList hold a strong reference to the peripheral once its discovered?

Comment: Update - Part of the problem I'm having is to get consistent results I have to cycle bluetooth on and off on the iPad.  I went back the heart rate monitor example and determined I am keeping a strong reference to the peripheral.  Now it consistently connects and immediately disconnects.

Comment: So this turns out to be a device specific challenge.  For reliability and security reasons the scanner remembers the last device it was connected to and that happened to be an Android pad I tested with.  So the scanner rejects connection attempts from other devices and disconnects. Thanks for the help @Paulw11.